# How to get type of values in Json Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I struggle with json file in robot framework:

*testy.json*

```
    "A": {
      "AA": "cacaca",
      "AB": "cbcbcb"
    },
    "B": ["ea", "eb"],
    "C": "aaa",
    "D": "bbb",
    "E": "ddd"
```

I tried to get all types in json file: 1st is dict, 2nd list, 3rd str.
The problem is when FOR loop pass "C" value ("aaa") in RF, it only pass aaa, which in Python is error - it skips quotation marks.
I need type of value, to make if statement later.

RF code: https://pastebin.com/WdbzXPcW

Cheers!

PS
It's my first question here, so "Hello World!" :D

Comment: Welcome to SO!! Please read [MCVE] and edit your post accordingly. and follow same in all future post. Do NOT put the screenshot of code. and don't put the external link of code as well. links may get expire. its better to put code as part of your post.

Comment: can you add how you want it to be used in if statement?

Answer (score 0):

You are close with your code.

All you have to do is not use the standard way variables are used in RF (`${variable}`), but use `$variable` instead:

```
${json_obj}=    Load JSON From File    file.json
${dict}=    Convert To Dictionary    ${json_obj}
${key_list}    Get Dictionary Keys    ${dict}
FOR    ${key}    IN    @{key_list}      
    ${value}=    Set Variable    ${dict['${key}']}     
    ${type}  Evaluate  type($value)
    Log To Console    ${type}     
END
```

this will give me:

```
<class 'dict'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

if I want a better-looking output, then:

```
${type}  Evaluate  type($value).__name__
```

which will give me:

```
dict
list
str
str
str
```

---

Also note that your json is not a valid json, so I added braces and made it valid (you can always check at https://jsonlint.com/):

```json
{
    "A": {
        "AA": "cacaca",
        "AB": "cbcbcb"
    },
    "B": ["ea", "eb"],
    "C": "aaa",
    "D": "bbb",
    "E": "ddd"
}
```